# sorting relation table in yii's view

Tags: yii

I am trying sorting in cListView.. which works perfectly fine for me with the sorting attributes from the same table.. i want to know if its possible to sort based on the fields from a related table..
for example..

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_viewnew',
        'sortableAttributes'=>array(
        'Code'

                ),
)); ?>
```

works fine..
but i wish to sort from another table field like this..

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_viewnew',
        'sortableAttributes'=>array(
        'relation_name.Make'

                ),
)); ?>
```

**this is what i have so far!! and doesn't work**

In my model

```
/**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'PMake'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PMake', 'ID'),
        );
    }
```

in my controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('table1');
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->together=true;
        $criteria->with=array('PMake');
        $dataProvider->criteria=$criteria;
        $dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder='PMake.Make ASC';

        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

in my view, **the sort here is what i'm trying to get to work.**

```
<?php 
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                'itemView'=>'_view',
                'sortableAttributes' => array('PMake.Make'=>'Make'),
                'loadingCssClass' => '', //remove loading icon
            )); 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This in Controller

```
 public function actionIndex()
        {
            $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('table1');
            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->together=true;
            $criteria->with=array('PMake');
            //Made changes here
            $criteria->order = 'PMake.Make ASC'
            $dataProvider->criteria=$criteria;

            $this->render('index',array(
                'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            ));
        }
```

Comment: still can't click on the `sort by` in the view